# Sentiment analysis with own lexicon

Tags: python

Hi i am supposed to make a sentiment analysis of the three sentences below. I am wondering how i will start this task because I am really stuck

I am supposed to write a function to determine the sentiment of a comment by using a word list as an
argument. Given a sentiment lexicon as follows:
• positive words: "good", "awesome", "excellent", "great"
• negative words: "bad", "broke", "terrible", "poor".

Then I need calculate the positive and negative words in the list in order to find out if the comment is positive or negative and print "positive comment" or "negative comment"

```
def splitandremovepunc(s):
    t = s.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation)
    return s.translate(t).split()
lst = ("Good for the price, but poor Bluetooth connections.")
lst2 = ("Excellent product. Awesome quality and good customer service.")
lst3 = ("The quality is terrible. I would not buy this product again.")
print(splitandremovepunc(lst))
print(splitandremovepunc(lst2))
print(splitandremovepunc(lst3))
```

Comment: Try writing something with this method: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count

Answer (score 0):

One of the most basic ways to do this is simple counting the number of negative and positive words in each string like so:

```
lst_split = ("Good for the price, but poor Bluetooth connections.").lower().split()
positive_word_list = ['good', 'great']
negative_word_list = ['bad', 'poor']
positive_score = 0
negative_scope = 0

for word in positive_word_list:
    positive_score += lst_split.count(word)
for word in negative_word_list:
    negative_score += lst_split.count(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

May I propose [VADER](https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment) (*Valence Aware Dictionary and sEntiment Reasoner*)? It’s a sentiment lexicon and you can use it like this:

```
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

sentiment_analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
result = sentiment_analyzer.polarity_scores('Good for the price, but poor Bluetooth connections.')
```

`result` is a dictionary that includes information concerning the sentence's sentiment polarity. The first three values (*neg, neu, pos*) are the portion of the text that is negative, neutral and positive. The last value stands for *compound score*, which represents the overall negativity or positivity score, normalised, ranging from -1 to +1.